# main Onclick except one div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have one problem and I don't know what can I do with this.
I have the follow code:

```
<main onclick="test()" id="main">
    <div id="test1"></div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
    <div id="test3"></div>
    <div id="NO-test4"></div>
    <div id="test5"></div>
    <div id="test6"></div>
    <div id="test7"></div>
</main>
```

With this, if I click on divs will execute "test()" function, how can I do if I want that div with id "NO-test4" don't execute this onclick?

Comment: did you try anything...?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a simple "write code for me" post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler you need to test the [`event.target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) to see whether the clicked element is the one you want to exclude. So you'd need to pass the `event` object to your function:

```
<main onclick="test(event)" id="main">
```

And then:

```
function test(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "NO-test4") return; // do nothing
    // code for other divs' clicks here
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzykkw4t/

If you remove the inline `onclick=` attribute and instead bind the click handler from your JS then the `event` object will be passed to your function automatically:

```
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click", test);
```

(That code would need to be in a script element after the "main" element, or within a document ready or onload handler.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzykkw4t/1/

Comment: Solved, it was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can put onclick in the needed divs :

```
<main id="main">
   <div id="test1" onclick="test()"></div>
   <div id="test2" onclick="test()"></div>
   <div id="test3" onclick="test()"></div>
  <div id="NO-test4"></div>
  <div id="test5" onclick="test()"></div>
  <div id="test6" onclick="test()"></div>
  <div id="test7" onclick="test()"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Not very scalable though, is it.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle `click` with `jquery`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#main").children('div').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "NO-test4")
            alert ('Disabled');
        else 
            test();      
    });                   
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pd3z66z4/3/)